# Jsh keeps running command endlessley

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hi all I recently came about jsh - it works very well for my use case , however It keeps running the command endlessly , and therefore keeps generating the sshtest.txt file (will make sense once the attached code is viewed) , How do I make it run only once??  I think that I need to end the thread its running in , but i'm not sure how. or I may have used the jsh syntax incorrectly and didn't set it to end the connection , I really am lost as it is.

```
package com.amex.lfu;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.hardware.biometrics.BiometricPrompt;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CancellationSignal;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelExec;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

//ssh shit starts here
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


public static String executeRemoteCommand(
        String username,
        String password,
        String hostname,
        int port) throws Exception {

    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    Session session = jsch.getSession("exiatron00", "192.168.0.10", 22);
    session.setPassword("password");

    // Avoid asking for key confirmation
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    session.setConfig(prop);

    session.connect();

    // SSH Channel
    ChannelExec channelssh = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    channelssh.setOutputStream(baos);

    // Execute command
    channelssh.setCommand("touch /home/exiatron00/Desktop/sshtest.txt && ~.");
    channelssh.connect();
    channelssh.disconnect();
    return baos.toString();


}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    final Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    final BiometricPrompt biometricPrompt = new BiometricPrompt.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("LFU")
            .setSubtitle("Place your finger on the scanner")
            .setDescription("Unlock your desktop")
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", executor, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                }
            }).build();
    Button authenticate = findViewById(R.id.authenticate);
    final MainActivity activity = this;
    authenticate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            biometricPrompt.authenticate(new CancellationSignal(), executor, new BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onAuthenticationSucceeded(BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult result) {
                    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Desktop Unlocked!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            final Handler handler = new Handler();

                            final Runnable r = new Runnable() {

                                public void run() {
                                    try {
                                        executeRemoteCommand("exiatron00","password","192.168.0.10",22);
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                                }
                            };

                            handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
                        }
                        public void stop() {
                            boolean exit = true;
                        }

                    });

                }
            });
        }
     });
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I am not familiar with the JSH, I can only guess here, but I'll do my best.
First off, I do not see any 'return' instructions aside from the one baos.toString().
Usually, I include those in most of my methods, but it is unlikely that this is the problem; worth a shot though.
Secondly (and once again, I do not know how JSH works), maybe the onClick function calls multiple times. Try something along the lines of

```
//Class start; static variables
static long time, time2, delay = 1000;
public Class(){
    this.time = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
//Other code
public static String executeRemoteCommand(String username,String password,String hostname,int port) throws Exception {
time2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
if(time2 - time < delay) { //Delay in MS
    return;//if delay threshold not reached
}
time = time2;//update last 'event'
//code intended on call here
```

to make sure it does not get called more often than (here) once per second.
This second solution would only be a workaround and there's a good chance it would only work on single-threaded processes, though, so I would not recommend it for obvious reasons.
If you decide to use it, I would recommend using different 'time' variables for different inputs, unless you want to have a global delay between inputs.